# Redirecting to different page for mobile is not working on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I wanted to reedirect my homepage to another static page for mobile. So i incorprated this code in the code snippet.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'tu_redirect_mobile' );
function tu_redirect_mobile() {
    if ( is_front_page() && wp_is_mobile()) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://asharficlothing.com/mobile/', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now the code works for every page and i am having no problem except on checkout page where the cursor goes to infinite wait stage and keeps on revolving and remain in the wait stage

Below is the screenshot of it:
[image]

Now when i was looking into the network section of chrome i found this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'tu_redirect_mobile', 10 );
   function tu_redirect_mobile() {
       if ( is_front_page() && wp_is_mobile()) {
       wp_redirect( 'https://asharficlothing.com/mobile/', 301 );
       exit;
    }
}
```

Try to use this hook `template_redirect`